# Why does `mouseup` preventDefault affect selected text differently?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Calling `mouseupEvent.preventDefault()` will *not* prevent creating a new selection in general, **unless** you try to create a selection within the current selection.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.broken')).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseup', ev => ev.preventDefault()))
```

```html
<div class="broken">
  Try selecting THIS TEXT, next try to click within the selection to deselect (select a collapsed selection.
</div>
<div class="broken" contenteditable>
  This is a contenteditable div, which makes the difference even far clearer, as it visualizes a collapes selection.
</div>
<div>
  And this is a normal div for reference without an event listener, when you select text in this div you can unselect it by clicking within the selection.
</div>
```

What is the reason for this difference in behavior between selected text and unselected text? I would expect the `preventDefault` call to *either* always prevent the creation of a new selection, or never to prevent the creation of a new selection.

For whatever it is worth, this behavior is consistent between Chrome and Firefox, but the spec states that there should not be a default action for mouseup:
[https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow-default-cancel:~:text=Yes-,None,-select](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow-default-cancel:%7E:text=Yes-,None,-select) and https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#mouseup . Given that there isn't a default action my understanding is that calling `preventDefault()` should *only* mark `defaultPrevented` to `true`.

---

## Goal

Figuring out whether this is or isn't a bug in the browser.

## Why did I call `preventDefault`?

I called it with the explicit goal of setting `defaultPrevented` to `true`, as my understanding was that it shouldn't have any side effects.

Comment: _"I would expect the preventDefault call to either always prevent the creation of a new selection, or never to prevent the creation of a new selection."_ - it never does prevent the creation of a _new_ selection to begin with (testing in a Chromium-based browser on Mac), I can do that in all three of the examples. The only difference is whether a single click (without keeping the button pressed and moving the mouse, to create a new selection) removes the current selection, or not. And even the latter doesn't behave consistently within the contenteditable element.

Comment: If your intention is to block text selection in the `.broken` elements then use CSS `user-select: none;`, but note that there's special rules applied to `contenteditable` elements so I doubt you'll be able to prevent text selections there

Comment: @CBroe Your comment starts with saying "it never prevents the creation of a new selection" and then you finish your comment by saying that it does. (A collapsed selection is just a type of selection). That latter behavior is exactly what I am asking about.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There is countless of trivial ways to prevent text selection. I am even pointing at the spec that states that there shouldn't be a default action, so why would I suddenly want there to be one?

Comment: @DavidMulder okay, mix-up between "technical" phrasing, and what is happening from the user perspective, is what I would call than then :-) "Creating a new selection", in my mind, was pressing the mouse button down, moving the cursor, and releasing the button again, to actually create a new, _visible_ selection. And that works in either case.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say deselection of text happens on mouseup, while selection of text happens on mousedown. Try:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.broken')).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseup', ev => ev.preventDefault())
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', ev => ev.preventDefault())
})
```

Comment: Note that this only works if you click on the element to start the selection. If you click outside it and drag over the text will still be selected

Comment: yeah, well... the question only asked "why is it different". Not sure what exactly OP is trying to accomplish...

Comment: Agreed, I wasn't intending to be overly critical. My assumption is that the OP is intending to prevent selection on the `.broken` elements.

Comment: -1 Deselection of text however still happens on mouseup even when preventDefault is called if I click elsewhere within the element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why would I want to prevent selection? I wouldn't be doing anything with the `mouseup` event if I was trying to prevent selection.

Comment: Then maybe explain what your goal is in the question. Note that, following your edit, 'Is this a bug or not' isn't a goal, and 99.9% of the time the answer will be a very resounding 'No'.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My goal is to understand whether any specification defines this behavior, because as far as I can tell it's against the spec that should guide this behavior. That's the goal. Once I identified this as the problem it was trivial to work around it, but writing code that works is the easy part 